# Ruby dynamically convert/ensure class

Tags: ruby

In ruby, for many classes, you can ensure that you have the correct class, or in some cases convert the class with code similar to the following.

```
Hash({a: 3}) #=> {a: 3}
Hash(3) #=> TypeError
```

However, this doesn't work if you're fetching the Class from a map or something else. For example, the following code throws a syntax error

```
type_map = {class: Hash}
type_map[:class]({a: 3}) #=> Unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

As does this:

```
klass = Hash
klass({a: 3}) #=> NoMethodError: undefined method klass for main:Object
```

Does anybody know of a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Kernel` module there are `Array` and `Hash` methods that creates arrays and hashes respectively.

When you type `Hash({a: 3})` you are calling this method, not the `Hash` class.

In your example, things change a little bit:

```
klass = Hash # Reference to a Hash class
klass({a: 3}) # try to access a method a method that doesn't exist in hash class
```

You can  change your example to:

```
method = Kernel.method(:Hash)
method.call({a: 3})
```

Comment: +1 This is the major confusion: Ruby allows a method and constant with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'm now using Kernel.respond_to?(klass.to_s) and Kernel.send(klass.to_s, val)

Comment: @Aaronneyer You should use `public_send` instead of `send` to indicated that your intention is not to bypass method visibility.